# Is there a way to get icon view when opening files?

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, files

When I try to select a picture to send in programs like Discord, I cannot tell what picture I am selecting. Is there any way I can make it use icon view?

[Picture of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVMmJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, GTK3 file open dialogs do not support listing the files in icon view rather than list view.

Applications, however, can provide a preview pane, for example "Gimp" or "Eye of Gnome":

[image]

There does not seem control for the user to display such pane or not. It is apparently the application that has to enable the preview pane. LibreOffice provides a "Preview" checkmark in its "Insert Image" dialog that allows the user to toggle such preview. So for now, it would appear this needs to be addressed by the developer of the application.

As a work around, you can select the file from the file manager. Usually, one can open files by drag and drop from the file manager. Alternatively, in a Open dialog, one can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and paste a file name / path to open a file.